# The NUnit 3.0 driver cannot support this test assembly

Tags: .net, unit-testing, nunit

This is intended to be a self-answered question, but if someone can provide a better answer, please do!

I'm trying to get started with NUnit. I installed NUnit 3.4 using the MSI installer, and I also installed the 3.2 test adapter. Then I created a simple project and a separate classes library for unit tests. Then I added a reference to the NUnit framework. The library builds fine, but when trying to run it either through the test adapter or using the command line runner, I get this message:

> The NUnit 3.0 driver cannot support this test assembly. Use a platform
>   specific runner.

There are no specific details as to *why* it cannot support this particular harmless test assembly. The test adapter provides an exception name as well, but it isn't particularly useful either.

Environment details: Microsoft Visual Studio 2013, .Net 4.5.

The question is: what's going on and, most importantly, how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When playing around with references I noticed that no matter what NUnit framework I choose from the list, when I close the project properties window and open it up again, I see a reference to the *portable* NUnit framework. The tooltip in the references list in the solution manager also shows a path containing the word “portable”. And it seems there is something with this portable framework that the test runner doesn't like.

As I don't need this portable framework, I tried to add the 4.5 framework specifically. It didn't work. No matter what I choose, the portable framework pops up!

So I decided to go the easy way and uninstalled NUnit, then reinstalling it using a “custom” installation with the portable framework deselected. Worked like a charm! Now when I add NUnit framework as a reference, the 4.5 framework is added, and it runs fine using the test adapter, right inside Visual Studio.

If someone knows how to fix it without uninstalling the portable NUnit framework, you're welcome to post another answer!

Comment: It is odd that Visual Studio is preferring the PCL assembly over the .NET 4.5 version. What version of .NET is your test assembly targeting?

Comment: Also, interesting that you prefer the MSI installer over NuGet. We were thinking of deprecating the MSI in favor of NuGet. I would be interested in knowing why you prefer an installed version.

Comment: @RobProuse, no reason to prefer MSI. I'm just not familiar with NuGet yet (I'm usually a Java programmer), and MSI seemed the usual way of installing stuff. Tried NuGet just now for NSubstitute, works cool. Maybe I should uninstall NUnit again and install with NuGet this time. As for the assembly, I just created a class library with default settings—nothing special. It set up automatically to target 4.5.

Comment: @RobProuse, oh, and another reason to prefer MSI, actually, is that I don't exactly have internet access on my development machine (security policies), so using any kind of online repository access becomes a bit complicated. I could probably set up a NuGet mirror/proxy or whatever, but that would require more than just “click to install”.

Answer (score 2):

I have created an issue for this at https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/1646

This was tested with the first NUnit 3.0 release and worked then, but it is likely that newer versions of Visual Studio is resolving references differently.

The workaround is to browse for the version of NUnit that you want instead of selecting it from **Assemblies | Extensions**. The .NET 4.5 version of the NUnit Framework installs to `C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\framework\{version}\net-4.5` by default.

Comment: Browse manually for a file? I thought about it, but I didn't like the idea of hardwiring absolute paths into the project.

Comment: I agree with the problem of absolute paths, but until we get this fixed, it is the only workaround I can think of. If it is a concern and NuGet doesn't work for you because of lack of Internet, you could add NUnit to a lib directory and use a relative path. Still, NuGet is the way to go. It is pretty hard to do .NET development these days without it.

Comment: it's certainly not the only workaround. It may be the only workaround for those needing the portable assembly as well, but I don't need it. So the option of not installing it to begin with is a better workaround for me.

Answer (score 0):

This error also happened to me but for only 1 out of the 50 test assemblies I had.  I fixed it by uninstalling the NUnit NuGet package for the project that failed, and then reinstalled it.  The problem it seemed fix was an incorrect Hint Path in the project file.  After that was fixed, the test assembly ran without that error.

Comment: It doesn't even happen to me with NuGet at all. The problem was with MSI install.